# Clarification on state_version and transaction_version change in Cumulus parachain template

Tags: parachain, runtime

I have some simple question. What `state_version` stands for, and when it should be changed?

As I can see, in [Cumulus parachain template](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/polkadot-v0.9.18/parachain-template/runtime/src/lib.rs#L176-L177) on `polkadot-v0.9.18` tag the `state_version` was changed to 1. 
 Also, `transaction_version` was increased, but when I compare extrinsic ordering and metadata [on our chain (between 0.9.16 and 0.9.18)](https://github.com/dappforce/subsocial-parachain/compare/b9bfbb5ecd6b97d3f3e2a9f6a9724d0d428897a4...v0.1.4), it looks like `transaction_version` need not change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `state_version` is related to migration to a new version of the representation of the key-value trie. I think if you start a new chain, it's better to use the latest version from the start. At the moment of writing, I think it's the version 1.

Changing `transaction_version` is just a way to communicate that the transaction/extrinsic became incompatible with another version. For example, in case you change parameters of a dispatchable to something else, you will need to bump the `transaction_version` or else a user sent transaction might be misinterpreted.

And, btw, those are not related to Cumulus but rather are coming from Substrate.

See documentation to those methods [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/88731ed619f6be1280f01cc8f02f10e2fb4cf199/primitives/version/src/lib.rs#L201-L214).